# Import image to QGIS using GEE plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, google-earth-engine, addlayer

I have download today the Google Earth engine plugin to QGIS using  this:
https://gee-community.github.io/qgis-earthengine-plugin/

I have tried to upload the image as shown in the example :
[image]

I have coped the code but for some reason I get erro and can't add the layer:

```
import ee
from ee_plugin import Map
image=ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2").filterBounds(Map.getCenter()).first()
Map.addLayer(image, {'min':500, 'max':5000, 'gamma': 1.4, 'bands': ['B4','B3','B2']}, 'image')
```

then I get the error:

> raise ee_exception.EEException(json_content['error']['message'])
>   ee.ee_exception.EEException: Image.visualize: Parameter 'image' is
>   required.

I believe I have define the visualization and that there is an image, so why do I get this error?

My endgoal is to be able to upload images to QGIS using GEE plugin

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably the result of lines 4-5, where the image is queried using the current map center but the code to set the map center is on line 8. This results in an empty image as the map center is ambiguous. You can check that by adding printing image info just after the image is queried on line 6:

```py
    print(image.getInfo())
```

Try moving Map.setCenter() to run before lines 4-5, or manually zoom in to some area in the QGIS map where you expect Sentinel-2 images to be present.

If your goal is "to be able to upload images to QGIS using GEE plugin", then you may need to use EE Export.image.* API (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting) to start export tasks, maybe using QGIS to get proper arguments for that function such as region.